# Events Made Easy Wordpress Plugin PayPal Checkout Not Working

Tags: wordpress, paypal

I've entered the Merchant ID. This seems to be the only option I can see that could cause an issue with allowing customers to pay via PayPal.

The other option I have selected is the "use sandbox" option rather than live, I have tried the LIVE option just in case. But I get the same result.

Upon clicking the checkout button, this request is sent via POST:

```
amount  8
business    [took this out for security, just to be safe]
cancel_return   http://holacuba.co.uk/events/?eme_pmt_result=fail&e
me_pmt_rndid=5aa80783a74a4_18067d0c90ff6f587f590d9486679b18
charset utf-8
cmd _xclick
currency_code   GBP
item_name   Booking+for+'Hola+Cuba+Wednesday+Salsa'
item_number 9
no_shipping 1
notify_url  http://holacuba.co.uk/events/?eme_eventAction=paypal_notification
quantity    1
return  
rm  2
```

To the endpoint here:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

The next step is supposed to be where a user would sign into PayPal.

I get forwarded to a PayPal, to a 302 page that reads

> Things don’t appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later.

I'm here on the recommendation of the Plugin author who was kind enough to get back to me but suggested it was a PayPal issue and not an issue with the plugin itself (if it was, I would assume lots of other people would have complained in the forums etc).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Nice useless error message from PayPal. Many things can cause that error. If you're using $_GET variables you should be using $_POST. Also apparently too much button text can throw that error. Try a shorter item name. Not having a 'billing address' set can throw the error. Many other possible causes.

Comment: Agreed! It is sent via $_POST.

This is the "buy" button. So the next step *should be* where the user would either sign into paypal, or enter payment information.

I'll try a shorter item name.

Comment: Tried to shorten the item name (I'm using a plug in, so limited to how much I can edit) to a 16 character item_name. Still the same error.

I've been in touch with the Plugin author and he assures me its fine. I still don't know whether this is a plugin problem, or a paypal problem? 

This POST is being sent to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

The error I get back is a 302.

Could it be the plugin is just aimed at the wrong endpoint?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry. Like I said, from a quick Google there are many potential causes of that error message. I simply listed the first few I saw. Try using the PayPal button generator to generate the same kind of button, make sure it works, then compare that with the button outputted by the plugin. Then change things one by one. You *can* edit the plugin code while you're trying to figure out the problem. Once you know the solution you can find a way to change the code which won't get overwritten by a plugin update or get the author to import your fix.

Comment: That's something for me to try, thanks! Unfortunately, the author pushed an update that broke this functionality and now its not generating a checkout button at all.

I appreciate your time. 

Going to close this question as this particular error is now not reproducible, and I have another completable different problem with the plugin.

Needless to say, I think I'm going to chin off this plugin and look elsewhere for a solution!

Comment: No problem, good luck! I'd also recommend looking for an alternative to PayPal if you can. Personally, PayPal has always been frustrating to use and has a mess of a UI and perpetually outdated docs.

Comment: Personally I'd use Omnipay because it's already a finished product that works and is a universal approach to payment handling, regardless of the provider; https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried everything I could think of as I liked the plugin.

Ended up using Open Tickets that is built on top of WooCommerce. Seems a lot more full featured, and had lots of tutorial videos that explained the nuances of setting it up.

I'm not a salesmen for OpenTickets, but I legitimately think it was a good free plugin that solved my issue, and wish I had tried it first.